# Getting sum in the gridview data without database

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a *Grid View* that a user will only add data to it. But data is not being saved into a database.

What i want to happen is to be able to Compute & Show the SUM of all the data's amount.

Here is the *Grid View*:
[image: Grid View]

I want the sum into the textbox. So, what i did was

CODE BEHIND:

```
 void gettotal()
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            float GTotal = 0f;
            for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                string Amount = GridView1.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[4].Text;
                GTotal += Convert.ToSingle(Amount);
            }
            txtSubTotal.Text = GTotal.ToString();
        }
    }

    protected void AddProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetPO();
        gettotal();
        AddNewRecordRowToGrid();
    }
```

Whenever `Button Add Product` is clicked, it will add into the gridview.

I tried the code and gets an ERROR of

> Input string was not in a correct format.
>
> Line 375: GTotal += Convert.ToSingle(Amount);

***EDIT #1***

*ADDITIONAL:* I am trying to get the amount as to when the btn add product is clicked. Will that work for me to find the value of the Amount?

So i changed the code to

```
string Amount = GridView1.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[4].Text;
//string Amount = GridView1.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[4].Text;
GTotal += string.IsNullOrEmpty(Amount) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt16(Amount);`
```

Still says NULL

Comment: What value you have in Amount the time you get error?

Comment: Are you sure that's what it says? Because in your code you have `Convert.ToInt16` but your error is on `Convert.ToSingle`.

Comment: Where is `GTotal += Convert.ToSingle` in your code ? If you are using this anywhere in your code then make sure that you are passing correct `CultureInfo` with the same. Convert.ToSingle is culture-sensitive.

Comment: i get the same error for `Convert.ToInt32` and `Convert.ToSingle` my bad

Comment: @Adil oh yeah.. so i changed the codes to `String Amount = (GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("Amount") as Label).Text;` there it went the error saying `null` for amount

Comment: FindControl returns null if control could not be found, check if the label has id Amout or something else

Comment: okay i was able to look for the amount. i used the codes given by RJK
but it does only get the last value. What should i do to get all the values and sum it all @Adil

Comment: HERE IS THE CODE
`string Amount = GridView1.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[4].Text;
if (!int.TryParse(Amount, out i)) i = 0;
GTotal += i;`

Answer (score 0):

I think if the Cell value is `null / empty`, throws an exception Input string was not in a correct format.

You have to avoid this problem, by checking the condition.

*Try this:*

```
string Amount = GridView1.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[4].Text;
GTotal += string.IsNullOrEmpty(Amount) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt16(Amount);
```

If you're looking to default to 0 with any non numeric input:

```
int i;
string Amount = GridView1.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[4].Text;
if (!int.TryParse(Amount, out i)) i = 0;
GTotal += i;
```

***Edit #1***

You need to make sure the `Rows and cells` are available and its not null / empty.

Here you might need to check additional conditions. Based on your data availability in Grid.

```
if(GridView1.Rows[row.RowIndex] != null && GridView1.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[4] != null)
{
    // Put the two lines of code here.
}
```

The above code is not tested one. Modify the `if condition` accordingly.

Comment: the amount is null :( am i using the wrong codes for it to see the value?

Comment: Nop, You just need to replace two lines of code, to just get this work. :) Cool.

Comment: i am putting the code when the btn addproduct is clicked (so data will be added to the gridview) and the the sum should view. will that be okay?

Comment: it does get only one value. which is the last value in my gridview. cell amount huhuhu

Comment: i wanted it to have a sum of all the data that the user will insert